# Dynamic JFreeChart at 30 second intervals

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am new in JFreeChart and new to Java also.

I have this data from our claims table:

> SEQ        IP_CLAIMS_RECEIVED HB_CLAIMS_RECEIVED IP_AVERAGE_RESPONSE HB_AVERAGE_RESPONSE
>   30 Seconds 29                 19             4               4

This data every 30 seconds will change giving the amount of claims processed and with the avarage seconds it took to process this.

So my graph I want it on the Y-Axis to display the round seconds like (0,,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40) and then on the X-Axis to display the time - the 30 seconds intervals showing the refresh times. And then the spike-lines would show the average-response times... And if it will be possible have two combined graphs one for IP Claims and another for HB Claims. I have a perfect [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048863/230513) of the graph but its confusing me a bit here is the code of it below:

```
package timeseriesdemo;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.data.time.DynamicTimeSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.data.time.Second;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852 */
public class TimeSeriesDemo extends ApplicationFrame {

    private static final String TITLE = "Dynamic Series";
    private static final String START = "Start";
    private static final String STOP = "Stop";
    private static final float MINMAX = 100;
    private static final int COUNT = 2 * 60;
    private static final int FAST = 100;
    private static final int SLOW = FAST * 5;
    private static final Random random = new Random();
    private Timer timer;

    public TimeSeriesDemo(final String title) {
        super(title);

        final DynamicTimeSeriesCollection dataset =
            new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(1, COUNT, new Second());
        dataset.setTimeBase(new Second(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2011));
        dataset.addSeries(gaussianData(), 0, "Gaussian data");
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);

        final JButton run = new JButton(STOP);
        run.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
                if (STOP.equals(cmd)) {
                    timer.stop();
                    run.setText(START);
                } else {
                    timer.start();
                    run.setText(STOP);
                }
            }
        });

        final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
        combo.addItem("Fast");
        combo.addItem("Slow");
        combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if ("Fast".equals(combo.getSelectedItem())) {
                    timer.setDelay(FAST);
                } else {
                    timer.setDelay(SLOW);
                }
            }
        });

        this.add(new ChartPanel(chart), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        btnPanel.add(run);
        btnPanel.add(combo);
        this.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        timer = new Timer(FAST, new ActionListener() {
            float[] newData = new float[1];

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                newData[0] = randomValue();
                System.out.println("dataset1 : " + dataset.advanceTime());
                dataset.advanceTime();
                dataset.appendData(newData);
            }
        });
    }

    private float randomValue() {
        System.out.println("randomvalue : " + (float) (random.nextGaussian() * MINMAX / 3));
        return (float) (random.nextGaussian() * MINMAX / 3);
    }

    private float[] gaussianData() {
        float[] a = new float[COUNT];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = randomValue();

        }

        return a;
    }

    private JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
        final JFreeChart result = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
            TITLE, "hh:mm:ss", "Claims Received", dataset, true, true, false);
        final XYPlot plot = result.getXYPlot();
        ValueAxis domain = plot.getDomainAxis();
        domain.setAutoRange(true);
        ValueAxis range = plot.getRangeAxis();
        range.setRange(-MINMAX, MINMAX);

        return result;
    }

    public void start() {
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TimeSeriesDemo demo = new TimeSeriesDemo(TITLE);
                demo.pack();
                RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
                demo.setVisible(true);
                demo.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited your minimal changes to my [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5048863/230513) to restore the attribution, which is [_required_](http://stackexchange.com/legal).

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116556).